# Android SDK location in OSX - Has it been actually installed by Unity Hub?

Tags: macos, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk, android-sdk-tools

We are using Unity 2018.3.8f1.

We have added Android Build Support from Unity Hub - Add Component:

[image: Unity Hub - Components installed]

But if we go to Unity Preferences - External Tools, the Android SDK location is empty:

[image: Android SDK location empty]

I have not been able to find the location of the Android SDK folder anywhere. I'm wondering if the component installed by Unity Hub is something different to Android SDK. Maybe it must be installed separately from: https://developer.android.com/studio?pkg=tools#downloads?

**UPDATE**

So far I have installed "Command line tools only" from the previous link. Then, I have installed OpenSDK (Vistual Studio did it for me: it asked me to update and install it as one of the things to update).

But when I opened tools/bin/sdkmanager, it said "Java is not installed". So I also installed Oracle Java SDK. Unfortunately tools/bin/sdkmanager returned errors after it. I applied a few workarounds I found by googling the errors. Still not luck.

So I have moved to the **easy way: installing the full version of Android Studio**. If we choose custom, we'll see that Android SDK Platform is going to be installed:

[image: screenshot wizard installation android studio]

**So it is working, but** I still have not idea of how many things I have **duplicated** on my system **wasting space**. I have:

- The Android component installed from Unity Hub
- Android Studio installed, which comes with the emulator and the IDE (I don't need them)
- OpenSDK (installed by Visual Studio)
- An embedded version of Java in Unity
- Oracle Java

Are they all actually needed? I don't think so!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only thing you are wondering is if the component installed by Unity hub is something different to Android SDK... the short answer is yes. You have to download it on the Android Developer SDK website you linked in the question. You only need the SDK under "Command line tools only" at the bottom of the page. If you do this you also need to download the jdk separatly [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! To combat link rot, please [edit] your answer to include the relevant parts of the link in your answer and provide the link for reference only. Thanks!